# VB macro in MS Word Inconsistently formatting Arabic Text

Tags: vba, ms-word, arabic

I wrote the following macro for MS Word. It works sometimes, but not consistently. I would love some help identifying what the problem might be with the code. Thanks in advance.

**The macro should perform the following tasks.**

1. In a paragraph containing English text and non-English text:

- Apply the Arabic font (Noto Naskh Arabic UI) to each instance of non-English text
- Set each instance of non-English text to 18-point    font size

2. In a paragraph containing only non-English text:

- Apply the Arabic    font (Noto Naskh Arabic UI) to each instance of non-English text
- Set each instance of non-English text to 18-point font size
- Right-align    the entire paragraph

**Issues**

- Non-English text doesn’t change font size in either scenario.
- The right-alignment isn’t consistently applied in the second scenario.

```
Sub Arabic()

    For Each myPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If myPara.Range.LanguageID = 9999999 Then
            For Each myWord In myPara.Range.Words
                If myWord.LanguageID <> wdEnglishUS Then
                    myWord.Font.Name = "Noto Naskh Arabic UI"
                    myWord.Font.Size = 18
                Else
                    myWord.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                End If
            Next myWord
        ElseIf myPara.Range.LanguageID <> wdEnglishUS Then
            myPara.Range.Font.Name = "Noto Naskh Arabic UI"
            myPara.Range.Font.Size = 18
            myPara.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        End If
        
    Next myPara
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of applying local formatting, which is what your code is doing now, consider create a linked style (which handles both paragraph and character formatting) using the font, size, language and paragraph alignment you want. Then in code, apply that style to text found in the selected language. BTW, your first scenario of mixed languages can't work, because you're trying to use the paragraph object to capture pieces of text that are smaller than a paragraph.

Comment: You do realize that Find and Replace can look for languages and apply formatting, don't you? It will prove far more efficient than trying to process paragraphs and words individually.

Comment: Neither Find/Replace nor the macro works consistently, but so far the macro is a little better. The F/R doesn't right-align paragraphs that contain solely non-English text, but the macro does.